# owl carousal design change

Tags: jquery, css, carousel

I have created a carousal with OWL Carousal with the following code,

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
    autoPlay: false,
    singleItem:true,
    transitionStyle:'fade',

});
```

It is showing slider like below,

[image]

I need to change the design like below,
I mean half of prev and next image needs to show.as follows,
[image]

[**Fiddle  demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8bj9br5u/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can small change to your jQuery code:

```
  $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      autoPlay: 3000, //Set AutoPlay to 3 seconds
      **singleItem:false,-------------------------->change this remove true and add false**
      navigation : true,
      navigationText : ["prev", "next"],
      itemsDesktop : [1199,3],
      itemsDesktopSmall : [979,3]

  });
```

Next-prev then you add this:

```
navigation : true,
navigationText : ["prev", "next"],
```

Comment: navigation : true,
navigationText : ["prev", "next"],----add in bottom single item

Comment: Could you please check my second image,I need only change design like that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.owl-item{width:auto !important}
```